# Require file input to have a file in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi is it possible to check to see if the input file type has a file in it before a function is run. I need to somehow disable the submit button unless the user inputs a file.

```
<script>

$(function() {

var bar = $('.progress-bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#uploaderForm').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    $( "#progressBar" ).removeClass('disappear').addClass('appear');
    $( "#submitFileUpload" ).addClass('disappear');
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
},

success: function() {
    var percentVal = '100%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
complete: function() {
$( "#status" ).text("Great, your upload was completed successfully.").removeClass('disappear');
$( "#progressBar" ).removeClass('appear').addClass('disappear');
setTimeout(function() {
 window.location.href = "/thanks";
}, 2000);
},

}); 

 })();  


     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to bind a function on input value change and set a flag

```
var flag = false;
$('#uploaderForm input[type="file"]').bind('change', function(event){
   if(event && event.target && event.target.files[0]){
      flag = true;
   }
});
```

Comment: You my friend are a life saver! Cant thank you enough.